# Retrieve Zebra Printer information vb.net

Tags: vb.net, zebra-printers

I have a zebra ZE500 barcode/label printer/applicator installed on a piece of manufacturing equipment. 
We have designed an application to send labels to the printer/applicator using vb.net and bartender for label design. 
I would like to be able to retrieve some information from the printer if possible.
-Is the print buffer empty or how many jobs/labels are in the print buffer.

-Is it possible to limit the amount of labels/jobs I can store in the printer?

My goal is to keep tabs on how many labels are in the printer, maybe keep a "1 piece flow" as they are applied. If I knew the printer was empty, I would send one label at that time.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I think the `~HS` command will be the closest you will get.

Comment: I can try the ~HS. I can send the command to the printer over the ip and port, that is easy. I will need to figure out how to "listen" for a response. Thanks!

Comment: When using a `TCPClient` I just used a Timer to check for any data that was received but there may be better ways. I had been using a serial port and the switch to Ethernet was quick last minute change so I didn't have a chance to study what the best method might have been.